# Hash password with salt in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash

How can I hash a password with salt in sql server?
Using any good hashing algorithm, I just want to do that stuff in Sql server.

Comment: Please tell us some more informations. What programming language do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can hash the password with Sql Server. You have to do it before.

As a good hashing algorithm i would suggest an implementation of BCrypt, Scrypt or PBKDF2.

For further informations about hashing and salting you may visit https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm.